# JOptionPane shows up not in the right moment

Tags: java, swing

I have problem with JOptionPane. I have created contructor in which I defined JOptionPane. I need to create object of that class in another class where I created JFrame. The problem is that JOptionPane opens before JFrame does and I want it to be just the opposite.

Every time i create an object of the class with JOptionPane it shows up.

I simply want to JOptionPane show and change "delay" only when I click "play" on my JMenu.

```
public class Gameplay extends Paint implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

private Timer timer;
private int q = 0;
private int delay;

public Gameplay() {
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    timer = new       Timer(delay=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("set Speed")), this);
    timer.start();
}

public class PlayGame implements IbeVisible {

JFrame f2 = new JFrame("Snake");

Gameplay gameplay = new Gameplay();

public void openGame() {

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    f2.setSize(900, 700);
    f2.setResizable(false);
    f2.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - f2.getWidth() / 2, dim.height / 2 - f2.getHeight() / 2);
    f2.add(gameplay);

}
 public void beVisible() {
    f2.setVisible(true);
}

public class Menu {

PlayGame playGame = new PlayGame();
JFrame menu = new JFrame();

void create() throws IOException {

    createMenuBar();
    menu.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("logo.png")))));
    menu.setTitle("Menu");
    menu.setVisible(true);
    menu.setSize(355, 400);
    menu.setResizable(false);
    menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void createMenuBar() {

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem play = new JMenuItem("Play");

play.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
    playGame.openGame();
    playGame.beVisible();
    });
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Comment: Well, I have read it already but still does not manage to rewrite me code properly, keep in mind I'm completly newby...

Comment: You seem to know how to add a menu bar to a frame. You seem to know how to execute code when a menu item is selected (i.e. using an ActionListener). You seem to know that a JOptionPane is displayed when calling JOptionPane.showInputDialog(). You want a JOptionPane to be displayed when a menu is selected. So, assemble the puzzle: the call to JOptionPaneLshowInputDialog must be inside the ActionListener added to the play menu item. Not in the constructor of PlayGame, which isn't called at that moment.

Comment: That was so obvious... Well, thank you sir!